# Let $A$ be bounded below, and $B = \{b \in R : b$ is a lower bound for $A\}$. Show that $\sup B = \inf A$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

This is   Exercise 1.3.3 (a) from "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbot, , [page 17](https://books.google.com/books?id=JXvBBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA17):

> Let $A$ be bounded below, and define $B = \{b \in R : b$ is a lower bound for $A\}$. Show that $\sup B = \inf  A$.

Please check my proof:

Suppose $A$ be bound below, it exist number $N\leq n$ for every $n\in \mathbb R$ in the set and $N$ is $\inf{A}$. Then $B=\{b \in \mathbb R:b$ is a lower bound for $A\}$. It exist number $b$ in the set, since it contains only lower bound of $A$ then it has number $b\leq M$ for every $b$ and $M$ is $\sup$ of $B$. But $b$ is lower bound of $A$ and $A$ has $N$ as $\sup$, $N$ is in $B$. $N$ is automatically is sup of $b$ therefore $M=N$ or $\sup {B}=\inf {A}$.

Comment: wait ,why edited my question ?

Comment: Is this an exercise in a book or you just come up with it?

Comment: @juniven exercise from Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbot

Comment: What page  please?

Comment: it is in page 17

Comment: There I see Exercise 1.3.3 (a) Thank you.

Comment: I think it doesn't happen $N$ is in $B$ necessarily.

Comment: I see fine this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461732/proof-that-inf-a-sup-b

Comment: @joseabp91 Thank ^ ^

Comment: @Fourier I was about to answer your question, but as joseabp91 pointed out, I think you need to look it out. In case you can't follow the proof there, I am willing to post my answer. Just chat with me.

Comment: You question was edited as your typesetting was a bit unusual. Moreover, the body of the post should be self-contained and not depend on the content of the title (which in turn was/is a tad on the too complicated side for a title).

Answer (score 3):

$\inf A$ is defined as the biggest lower bound of $A$. So it is in particular a lower bound of $A$. But that means it is an element of $B$, which is defined as the set of all lower bounds of $A$. Thus $\inf A\in B$. But it is also the biggest lower bound of $A$, so for every $b\in B$ follows $b\leq\inf A$. This gives us $\inf A=\max B$. But if a set has a maximum, this maximum is also its supremum. Thus $\inf A=\max B=\sup B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma 1**

If $Y$ is a subset of partial ordered set $X$ that has maximum/minium then it has supremum/infimum too and it is equal to maximum/infimum.

**Lemma 2**

If $X$ is a set of real numbers that has an upper/lower bound then it has supremum/infimum too.

**Theorem 3**

If $X$ is a set of real numbers that has an upper/lower bound then the supremum/infimum of $X$ is the infimum/supremum of the set of the upper/lower bound of $X$.

*Proof*. If $X$ is a set of real numberst that has an upper/lower bound then by previous lemma it has supremum/infimum too so that we show that the supremum/infimum is the infimum/supremum of the upper/lower bounds. So if $\upsilon:=\sup X$ then it is the minimum of the upper bound of $X$ and if $\lambda:=\inf X$ then it is the maximum of the lower bound so that in any case the theorem follows by first lemma.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any rep yet, so I cannot comment. I believe @Bentapair solution is on the right track but not entirely right (at least in context of the problem). This problem is asking us to show that $\inf A$ does exist from the Axiom of Completeness. I think a better solution is to show that $\sup B$ exists, it is the largest of all lower bounds for $A$, and $\sup B\in B$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).