# proving sup B = sup A

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Looking at the following question from Abbot:

(a) Let A be nonempty and bounded below, and define $B =
\{b ∈ R : b $ is a lower bound for A$\}. $ Show that $ sup B = inf A$

Is this not a counter example?:

$A = \{6,7,8\}, B = \{3,4,5\}$

A is bounded below, and every element in B is a lower bound of A. However infA = 6 and supB = 5.

I'm guessing that $B =
\{b ∈ R : b $ is a lower bound for A$\}$ implies that B contains **all** lower bounds of A. But in what way does the definition say this? Am I misinterpreting something fundamental in the way sets are defined?

Comment: $B$ should include *all* lower bounds of $A$.

Comment: But why does it include all lower bounds of A? Where in the definition does it explicitly say that it contains all lower bounds? Please excuse my naivety

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thanks, this is what I was after. I appreciate it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2099966

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you were misinterpreting [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).

Also, any sentence of the form "$B=...$" uniquely identifies $B$ as the object denoted by the term after the equals sign. There's no expression that gives you a choice for what it denotes.

Comment: Actually there are exceptions like $b=\pm2$ or $f=O(n^2)$, where a symbol changes the meaning of a nearby equals sign, but these are rare and somewhat informal.